# Add Toaster inside config angular js

Tags: angularjs, config

I am able to add toaster successfully in service of angular js. But not able to add to config file.

Kindly help me to add toaster inside angularjs config file.

Note: I just wanted to add exception messages as toaster for all the files. so that wanted to add this toaster in core.config file.

Answer (score -1):

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{
  'closeButton': false,
  'debug': false,
  'position-class': 'toast-top-right',
  'onclick': null,
  'showDuration': '200',
  'hideDuration': '1000',
  'timeOut': '5000',
  'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
  'showEasing': 'swing',
  'hideEasing': 'linear',
  'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
  'hideMethod': 'fadeOut'
}"></toaster-container>




angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', [
    '$scope', 'toaster', function($scope,toaster) {

    toaster.pop('success', 'message', 'some message');

}]);

you can also refer the following urls

https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

https://foxandxss.github.io/angular-toastr/
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your reply.

```
angular.module('myprofile')
    .factory('PeService', PeService);


ProfileService.$inject = ['toaster'];
function PeService(toaster) {
    ...
}
```

this works fine for me. But

```
angular.module('core').config(coreConfig);

coreConfig.$inject = ['$provide','toaster'];
function coreConfig($provide,toaster) {
    ... 
}
```

is not working for me